# How to display datetime form mysql using CakePHP 3.0

Tags: mysql, datetime, cakephp-3.0

I would like to ask how to add `datetime ('Y-m-d h:i:s')` format field for the SQL.

The name of my table is **groups**, the name of the field is **date_add**
i am using cake PHP 3, i want to use the timezone **Australia/Perth** but i don't know how to begin.

I successfully displayed added my date using

```
$group->date_add = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

However, the result for the time is not correct with the timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Datetime in PHP in general**

Per the documentation of [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) you can use all options available for the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions for formatting. Your main mistake in the formatting is the difference betweetn a `y` and a `Y` being the difference between a year in two and a year in four numbers.

Secondly you say you want to add the correct time zone. This is a bit odd however since you always want to add the same time zone. If you want to convey the fact that all your dates are Australia/Perth as information why do you not simply add that text after it?

If you mean this is a problem since you store the information in a different time zone to begin with and thus have a conversion problem you can set the correct time zone on the DateTime object itself. But you need to be sure the DateTime object is constructed with the correct original time zone to begin with. Observe the following code for an explanation:

```
<?php
$DateTime = new DateTime(); // This is now Europe/Amsterdam for my laptop
var_dump($DateTime->format('dmY h:i e'));
// result of var_dump is: string(31) "13102015 12:00 Europe/Amsterdam"

$DateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
var_dump($DateTime->format('dmY h:i e'));
// result of var_dump is: string(28) "13102015 11:00 Europe/London"
```

Take aways:

1. e is the format modifier for the time zone
2. Conversion of time zones is possible with PHP's DateTime object. Find out what your default time zone is on your current PHP installation to see if you need to convert or not. See information on the date.timezone setting here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

**Cake 3.0 specific**

As Oops D'oh pointed out in the comments there are a lot of CakePHP specific things to know as well. Since he added an excellent part concerning that I suggest you read that as well.

Comment: Great, You might want to accept my answer in that case :) Good luck on your continued programming!

Comment: @SueLee This solution is ok when using default PHP. But as you are working with CakePHP 3 you should have a look at the [TimestampBehaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html) what is also interpreted by the great [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html). Please do the [beginner tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html) as this includes timestamp example. You can change the [default time zone](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/bootstrap.php#L85) in `/config/bootstrap.php/` in CakePHP

Comment: great addition, mentioned it specifically in the answer